# Drawing partial sprites in Java using the TextureRegion (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I currently have the class for my main character "Student", it has no behaviors except the left and right movements. I managed to make it so all the frames of my spritesheet will render, so I need help in drawing the first 3 frames (which are the walk cycle) when I press LEFT / RIGHT keys. 
Here's the spritesheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM5nu.jpg

Edit: AND 2nd and 3rd rows when pressing UP and Down Keys.

Student Class

```
    public class Student {

    private Texture player;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> playerAnimation;
    private int pX;
    private int pY;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private int HP;

    public Student(float speed, int x, int y){
        player = new Texture("student.png");
        TextureRegion[][] tmp= TextureRegion.split(player,450/3,450/3);
        TextureRegion[] character = new TextureRegion[9];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
                character[index++] = tmp[i][j];}
        }

        playerAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(speed,character);
        pX=x;
        pY=y;
    }

    public SpriteBatch getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    public void goLeft(){
        pX-=5;
        if(pX < -10){
            pX = -10;
        }
    }

    public void goRight(){
        pX+=5;
    }

    public void renderStudent(float stateTime){
        TextureRegion currentFrame = playerAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime,true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, (float) pX, (float) pY, 0, 0, currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),
                currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),1.5f,1.5f,0);
    }

    public void dispose(){
        player.dispose();
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
    public class HaxMain extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture bg;                                 

    float stateTime;

    private Student student1;
    private Guard mguard, fguard;
    private Admin madmin, fadmin;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();                        
        bg = new Texture("Level1.png");

        student1 = new Student(.5f, 100, 0);
        student1.setBatch(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);    
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                       

        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
            student1.goLeft();
            //Code to render image to the left
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
            //Code to render image to the right
            student1.goRight();
        }

        batch.begin();                                                  /*default code*/

        batch.draw(bg, 0, 0);
        student1.renderStudent(stateTime);
        batch.end();                                                
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        bg.dispose();
        student1.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: how many frames are inside `student.png` files , 3 frames are for running action then rest are ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan all of them are 3x3, the top row is the walking cycle. 2nd and 3rd rows are for entering or exiting a room, btw my game's sidescroller, the character can enter a room to hide when an enemy passes by. Here's one image http://imgur.com/a/HHdm9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Animation only for Running and use that animation to show your player is running left or right. You can flip TextureRegion according to direction of your player like this :

```
TextureRegion[] character;
boolean isRight;    

public Student(float speed, int x, int y){
    player = new Texture("student.png");
    TextureRegion[][] tmp= TextureRegion.split(player,450/3,450/3);
    character = new TextureRegion[9];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i <3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            character[index++] = tmp[i][j];}
    }

    TextureRegion runningFrames[]=new TextureRegion[3];

    for (int i=0;i<runningFrames.length;i++)
        runningFrames[i]= character[i];

    playerAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(speed, runningFrames);
    playerAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    pX=x;
    pY=y;

}

public void goLeft(){
    pX-=5;
    if(pX < -10){
        pX = -10;
    }
    if(isRight){
       isRight=false;
       for (TextureRegion textureRegion:playerAnimation.getKeyFrames())
           if(textureRegion.isFlipX()) textureRegion.flip(true,false);
    } 
}

public void goRight(){
    pX+=5;
    if(!isRight){
       isRight=true;
       for (TextureRegion textureRegion: playerAnimation.getKeyFrames())
           if(!textureRegion.isFlipX()) textureRegion.flip(true,false);
    }
}
```

Create another animation of other action and draw frame of animation using flag.

Comment: Ok I think I'm having progress here, I'm new in libgdx btw. I'm getting an error in the playerAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(speed, runningFrames, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);, it says it cannot resolve constructor for Animation(float, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion[], com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.PlayMode). Does it have something to do with my parameters in Student constructor?

Comment: I've just checked your update and it works! So for the other 2 behaviors (entering/exiting a room), basically I just have to create new animations, do i have to separate those frames and create their own spritesheet or is it possible to use the same frames after splitting the TextureRegion?

Comment: @ErrolEmpeño yes you're right create other animation and display using flag according to your requirement.

Comment: [flag](https://www.google.co.in/#q=flag+in+programming) is simple variable used mostly for conditional work